# copy.deepcopy(): Class with dictionary copied improperly

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-copy, python-class

Good evening!

I faced a problem with `copy.deepcopy()`. I wanted to copy a class which had `dict` self variable and got this result:

```
>>> import copy
>>> class A:
...     a = {'a': 1}
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.a
{'a': 1}
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> b.a
{'a': 1}
>>> b.a['a'] = 123
>>> b.a
{'a': 123}
>>> a.a
{'a': 123}
>>>
```

So, I copied class and assigned an item of dictionary in its copy and then original class changed too.
Why did't it copied dictionary too, or should I do this manually?

Answer (score 4):

you defined `A.a` as a class attribute, which is explicitly shared between the class, all subclasses and their instances. You can check `a.__dict__` and found no such key as `'a'`. To correctly create a attribute, you should set it in `__init__` function.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = {'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a class variable currently; there is only one instance of it. (It should be accessed as `A.a`.)

This does not make much sense; it should be an instance variable instead (so each instance of the class has a separate `dict`). You can set it in the `__init__` method.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = {'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import copy
>>> class A:
...     a = {'a': 1}
...
```

This causes **the class `A` itself, not instances of that class** to contain an attribute `a` which is that dictionary.

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.a
{'a': 1}
```

**Looking up** an attribute in an instance can find the corresponding attribute of the class, if the instance doesn't directly store one with the same name, but it still conceptually part **of the class**.

```
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> b.a
{'a': 1}
```

As expected, `b` is a deep copy of `a`: that is to say, another instance of the same `A` class, with all of the same instance-specific data (i.e.: no instance-specific data, because `a` has no instance-specific data).

```
>>> b.a['a'] = 123
```

Assigning to `b.a` would cause `b` to have an `a` attribute separate from the class. However, this syntax **does not** do that - instead, it looks up the `a` attribute **from the class** (which is a dict) and **modifies** that `dict` object (and there is only one such `dict`).

```
>>> b.a
{'a': 123}
>>> a.a
{'a': 123}
>>>
```

Both `b.a` and `a.a` look up **the same** `dict` object - the one that is stored **in the class** - because **neither `a` nor `b`** has its own instance-specific `a` attribute.